# Tiny Death Star game state lost when phone battery runs out: Any way to retrieve game?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My phone got turned off when the battery ran out while I was playing and when I turned it on again everything in the game was gone. Does anyone know how to fix this and retrieve the game?

Comment: Which update do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to post what platform you're using.  iOS, Android, Win Phone, etc.

But, from what I've seen so far, there seems to be no way to recover your status unless you have a backup of the phone from right before the crash.  Even that seems to be questionable on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Android phone.  I had made a backup of TDS (using the Helium app) about 10 days before the crash.  I restored it, expecting that my tower would lose the last 10 days progress.  In fact, it returned to almost exactly the state it was in before the crash.  Clearly your tower state is being stored on a cloud server and the only thing getting corrupted in a crash is some sort of user ID.  The point is, even an old backup worked for me with no loss of progress.

Comment: Or the progress is not stored within the app itself, but in another file that was not part of the backup, but was now able to be accessed due to the reinstallation.  This can of course, be operating system dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The game automatically backs up your data every few hours on a cloud server. Unless you break your phone completely you will be able to get back your state when you log back in.

Comment: This assumes the latest update is installed.  In fact at the time of posting, this was not the case.